# k-fold validation when training neural networks

Tags: validation, machine-learning, neural-network, cross-validation

In 10-fold validation, at the beginning of each fold, are the weights initialized with a new set of random numbers ? Or, do the weights learnt in k-th fold act as the initial weights for the (k+1)-th fold?

Comment: They are re-initialized with new set of random numbers in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

K-fold validation is mainly used to evaluate the model when we cannot have a dataset for train, validation and test, if you will not initialize the algorith with a new set of random numbers, you risk to have a bias when you count the mean of the scores of cross validation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do we get the set of weights that can give highest accuracy to the network? I thought, if the weights learnt in previous fold act as the initial weights for the next fold, then at the end of k-fold validation, we can get the best and the most optimized set of weights.